# Failed to add liquidity in pancakeswap

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, truffle, uniswap

I am trying to make a few transactions on binance test net using a script in solidity and truffle which is a clone of PANCAKESWAP. I was able to successfully compile and execute the script once. When I tried to do it again on different addresses for router and factory it gave me the following error:

```
StatusError: Transaction: 0xc94424b8c6037e75e0eaf5f21982e2f73f88e71e18e0e5e783c642d6210e686f exited with an error (status 0). 
    at module.exports (D:\Blockchain\pancake\createpool\scripts\deploypool.js:18:18)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  tx: '0xc94424b8c6037e75e0eaf5f21982e2f73f88e71e18e0e5e783c642d6210e686f',
  receipt: {
    blockHash: '0xc4bea040096811e809c18216d85fc82813b60db9545d4e1bf6ab7c4dd344fe87',
    blockNumber: 8023495,
    contractAddress: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 699140,
    from: '0xe95745a8f4e3cdb1cf5bffd4a94f0b249e99f489',
    gasUsed: 29046,
    logs: [],
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    status: false,
    to: '0x7632ae832440032fb4ca93e56873a92a01b06e13',
    transactionHash: '0xc94424b8c6037e75e0eaf5f21982e2f73f88e71e18e0e5e783c642d6210e686f',
    transactionIndex: 2,
    rawLogs: []
  },
  reason: undefined,
  hijackedStack: 'StatusError: Transaction: 0xc94424b8c6037e75e0eaf5f21982e2f73f88e71e18e0e5e783c642d6210e686f exited with an error (status 0). \n' +
    '     Please check that the transaction:\n' +
    '     - satisfies all conditions set by Solidity `require` statements.\n' +
    '     - does not trigger a Solidity `revert` statement.\n' +
    '\n' +
    '    at Object.receipt (C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\packages\\contract\\lib\\handlers.js:124:1)\n' +
    '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)\n' +
    '    at Function.start (C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\packages\\contract\\lib\\override.js:49:1)'
```

My **truffle-config.js**:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
require('dotenv').config();
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

const infuraKey = process.env.infuraKey;
const mnemonic = process.env.mnemonic;

module.exports = {

  networks: {
    // Useful for testing. The `development` name is special - truffle uses it by default
    // if it's defined here and no other network is specified at the command line.
    // You should run a client (like ganache-cli, geth or parity) in a separate terminal
    // tab if you use this network and you must also set the `host`, `port` and `network_id`
    // options below to some value.
    //
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    rinkeby: {
      provider: function () {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/" + infuraKey);
      },

      network_id: 4,
      gas: 4500000,
      gasPrice: 10000000000,
    },

    bscTestnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(
        mnemonic,
        'https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545'
      ),
      from: '0xe95745a8F4E3cDb1cF5bfFD4A94F0B249e99f489',
      network_id: 97,
      gas: 4500000,
      gasPrice: 10000000000,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
    mainnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(
        mnemonic,
        'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'
      ),
      network_id: 56,
      gas: 4500000,
      gasPrice: 10000000000,
      skipDryRun: true
    }

  },

  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.0",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: false,
      //    runs: 200
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    },
  },
};
```

When i tried to do the same using a truffle command instead of the script it gave me the same error. The truffle command was:

```
pool.addLiquidity("0x84D2A9d0D51fd578c76908603bfdd91417F54915","0x22E692b514690757Bc26DE1C01d4Fc7207d30f90",4000,4000,7000,7000,"0xe95745a8F4E3cDb1cF5bfFD4A94F0B249e99f489",Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10).then(function(r){console.log(r);});
```

My liquidity functions are below:
I have even tried remove the assert statement and replacing it with an if but face the same error.

```
// **** ADD LIQUIDITY ****
    function _addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin
    ) private returns (uint amountA, uint amountB) {
        // create the pair if it doesn't exist yet
        if (INiftFactory(factory).getPair(tokenA, tokenB) == address(0)) {
            INiftFactory(factory).createPair(tokenA, tokenB);
        }
        (uint reserveA, uint reserveB) = NiftLibrary.getReserves(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
        if (reserveA == 0 && reserveB == 0) {
            (amountA, amountB) = (amountADesired, amountBDesired);
        } else {
            uint amountBOptimal = NiftLibrary.quote(amountADesired, reserveA, reserveB);
            if (amountBOptimal <= amountBDesired) {
                require(amountBOptimal >= amountBMin, 'NiftRouter: INSUFFICIENT_B_AMOUNT');
                (amountA, amountB) = (amountADesired, amountBOptimal);
            } else {
                uint amountAOptimal = NiftLibrary.quote(amountBDesired, reserveB, reserveA);
                assert(amountAOptimal <= amountADesired);
                require(amountAOptimal >= amountAMin, 'NiftRouter: INSUFFICIENT_A_AMOUNT');
                (amountA, amountB) = (amountAOptimal, amountBDesired);
            }
        }
    }
    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external override ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity) {
        (amountA, amountB) = _addLiquidity(tokenA, tokenB, amountADesired, amountBDesired, amountAMin, amountBMin);
        address pair = NiftLibrary.pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenA, msg.sender, pair, amountA);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenB, msg.sender, pair, amountB);
        liquidity = INiftPair(pair).mint(to);
    }
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external override payable ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity) {
        (amountToken, amountETH) = _addLiquidity(
            token,
            WETH,
            amountTokenDesired,
            msg.value,
            amountTokenMin,
            amountETHMin
        );
        address pair = NiftLibrary.pairFor(factory, token, WETH);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(token, msg.sender, pair, amountToken);
        IWETH(WETH).deposit{value: amountETH}();
        assert(IWETH(WETH).transfer(pair, amountETH));
        liquidity = INiftPair(pair).mint(to);
        if (msg.value > amountETH) TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(msg.sender, msg.value - amountETH); // refund dust eth, if any
    }
```

My **deploypool.js** file:

```
const Factory = artifacts.require('Factory.sol');
const Router = artifacts.require('Router.sol');
const Pair = artifacts.require('Pair.sol');
const Token1 = artifacts.require('token1.sol');
const Token2 = artifacts.require('token2.sol');

module.exports = async done => {
  try {
    //const [admin, _] = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    const factory = await Factory.at('0x81338c4e7a7f30297aF1dd1dBF02Fc1299b0EA12');
    const router = await Router.at('0x73D58041eDdD468e016Cfbc13f3BDc4248cCD65D');
    const token1 = await Token1.new();
    const token2 = await Token2.new();
    const pairAddress = await factory.createPair.call(token1.address, token2.address);
    const tx = await factory.createPair(token1.address, token2.address);
    await token1.approve(router.address, 10000);
    await token2.approve(router.address, 10000);
    await router.addLiquidity(
      token1.address,
      token2.address,
      9000,
      9000,
      10000,
      10000,
      'mymetamaskaddress',
      Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10
    );
    const pair = await Pair.at(pairAddress);
    const balance = await pair.balanceOf("0xe95745a8F4E3cDb1cF5bfFD4A94F0B249e99f489");
    console.log(`balance LP: ${balance.toString()}`);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  done();
};
```

**Address of verified router** https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x73D58041eDdD468e016Cfbc13f3BDc4248cCD65D#code

**Address of verified factory**
https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x81338c4e7a7f30297af1dd1dbf02fc1299b0ea12#code

**Previous Successful transaction with a different factory and router address**
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x9ca6e07ffcc0ab50c2f181783a14a17e850ad16dbd15c1590e4f2321cc9d44b5

Comment: can you verify your contracts on BSC testnet, please? it would get great if you can add the router and factory address on which your script worked (possibly included successful txn id as well)

Comment: Would recommend you to get your contracts verified and deployed on the bsc testnet and also add it to tenderly (https://tenderly.co/) and debug the failed tx there you will get the point of failure

Comment: @hack3r_0m this is the address of verified pancake factory https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x81338c4e7a7f30297af1dd1dbf02fc1299b0ea12#code and the address of the verified pancake router https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x73D58041eDdD468e016Cfbc13f3BDc4248cCD65D.

Comment: check my edited question for more details

Comment: can you verify the router & factory involved successful transaction as well? I will update my answer accordingly in the future if I find anything suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after spending days on this issue I came to know that I was just changing the init_hash once before multiple deployments over testnet. The init_hash changes everytime, so you have to copy the init_hash from pancake pair file into pancake library each time. After doing so I was able to successfully add liquidity using my own router and factory address over bsc testnet.

Comment: I think I am running into the same issue as you. Can you explain a bit more where this init_hash is? I looked in PancakePair.sol but I cannot find it

Comment: The init_hash is located in your PancakeFactory.sol file first you will deploy it and note down the value of hash. Then you will paste this hash value in PancakeLibrary.sol which is located in libraries folder of the periphery repo.

Answer (score 2):

your deploy script fails at:

```
await router.addLiquidity(...)
```

while making a call to addLiquidity(), when it reaches:

```
(uint reserveA, uint reserveB) = PancakeLibrary.getReserves(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
```

which in turn fails at:

```
(uint reserve0, uint reserve1,) = IPancakePair(pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB)).getReserves();
```

here the output of pairFor for tokenA and tokenB is `0x78715162d94936c07d811a03e3e0411a4270bf6c` while your tokens pair is deployed at [`0xb8c774F637C2B40d2a834Bb6c1EecD7c96166Cf9`](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xb8c774f637c2b40d2a834bb6c1eecd7c96166cf9). `_addLiquidity` fucntion of router creates the pair if it doesn't exists (checks by calling `getPair() == 0x000...0`) and if pair exists then calls `getReserves()` which in turn calls `pairFor()`. If you have made changes to PancakePair then init_hash might change and address calculated by `pairFor()` to find pair might be different. You can try removing createPair call to factory and check without it.

Comment: I calculated the init_hash now and added it to the pancake library and deployed and verified the new router again. Then called liquidity function and it still gave me the same error. This is the failed transaction 0x8090a672625fa79932d617ec460ae17a7ea975389604753804ed